# how can I modify Implementation-Version in manifest file?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, dependency-injection, jar

my project uses spring core-Implementation-Version: 5.0.10.RELEASE in all packages
I want to change it to 5.3.24 in all packages.
I searched "5.0.10.RELEASE" in project and it is written only in manifest file.
So I thought I need to change the Implementation-Version in MANIFEST.MF in spring-core-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar

How can I do that?

Comment: No you don't change it. What would you gain from it... INstead you should include the proper dependency in your maven build.

Comment: You have to upgrade your spring version.... not changhing some manifest files or alike...

Comment: @M.Deinum in my root pom.xml i add it as dependency but other classes don't see it if i don't add again

Comment: You really should learn how dependencies work and what a Manifest is. Also if you are mixing jars from different versions of spring (which it looks like) you are doing it wrong. Also you state you are using spring-boot (according to the tags) so if you are manually adding dependencies on different spring jars you are again doing it wrong. Please add your `pom.xml` to your question.